# Liteon hybrid usb dvb is not working in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, usb, dvb

I'm trying to install an hybrid usb dvb on ubuntu 13.10 but after looking for different answers in google i'm still in the same point, so the usb dvb does not work.

When I make dmesg|grep usb I recieve this:

```
new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.208182] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04ca, idProduct=f004
[    2.208185] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.208187] usb 2-4: Product: HYBRID-TV
[    2.208188] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: LITEON
[    2.208189] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 0000000100
```

So, I supose the usb stick uses an liteon hybrid dvb chip.
I have found the firmware (dvb-usb-dibusb-6.0.0.8.fw), I downloaded and I copied on /lib/firmware but nothing happend.

When In unplug and plug again the usb dvb I have this on the /var/log/syslog:

```
Feb  9 11:53:54 vento kernel: [  963.180273] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
Feb  9 11:53:58 vento kernel: [  966.656448] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Feb  9 11:53:58 vento kernel: [  966.789110] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04ca, idProduct=f004
Feb  9 11:53:58 vento kernel: [  966.789114] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb  9 11:53:58 vento kernel: [  966.789116] usb 2-4: Product: HYBRID-TV
Feb  9 11:53:58 vento kernel: [  966.789118] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: LITEON
Feb  9 11:53:58 vento kernel: [  966.789119] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 0000000100
Feb  9 11:53:58 vento mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-4"
Feb  9 11:53:58 vento mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
```

I read somwhere that this message -device was not an MTP device- is releated with the possibility that the usb stick does not recieve energy enough and should be changed to another usb port. I tried this also but not result.
So that is all.
Thank you for reading and if you know where the problem could be...